# Playing flash in DirectX game scene

Tags: flash, directx

I'm using DirectX to develop a little game, I'm working for a way to play *.swf* movie in the scene. AFAIK, DirectX doesn't support flash, so I must convert flash into texture sequences.   I have thought of two ways by now:

1. Using Direct Show. Implement a flash source filter and render to textures. But it's too complex for me to complete it.
2. Using the OLE to draw the flash and copy the buffer to textures. But I don't know whether it can work and where to start.

Is there anyone who know how to do this. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're just looking to use the SWF as a video, and not an interactive medium, you can try the [Gameswf library](http://tulrich.com/textweb.pl?path=geekstuff/gameswf.txt).

Comment: I got the Gameswf library. It's too complicated for me. I'll go deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this http://code.google.com/p/flash-to-directx/ ?
I don't really use that code but I use many of its technique to implement my own solution